# appcompat-v7:21.0.0 not working with google play service 6.1+

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat

I'm updating my app to bring material theme support(my app uses Google Play Services)

When I sync my project, this showed up:

```
...\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\6.1.11\res\values\wallet_colors.xml

Error:Attribute "showText" has already been defined
```

My gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'
// the latest version of play-services is 6.1.11
```

If I exclude appcompat-v7 then the project compiles without errors.

Did I got too excited about lollipop and didn't read the docs properly? How can I fix this?

Part of the build script:

```
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '21.0.1'
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries true
    //incremental true
}
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 11
    versionName '1.0'
    renderscriptTargetApi 21
    renderscriptSupportMode true
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

Local Google repository looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Try to define dependency like this `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'`

Comment: Yes I tried that, 6.1.+ resolves to 6.1.11

Comment: I have similar issue with 6.1.11 version. It complains about "color" attribute in wallet_colors.xml which belongs Play Services library

Answer (score 19, accepted):

@igavran answer points to the right direction but I wanted to give more comprehensive answer, so there it is:

Gradle [Resource Merger](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-merging) merges all resource folders from all dependencies and place into single folder. In case there are duplicates build process will fail.

For some weird reason, Android Studio points to the *wallet_colors.xml* of the Google Play Service library in the Messages window. Google Play Service has nothing to do with this problem. Fortunately, if you look below under *Output:* label, you will find the right path to the problem e.g.

[image: Screenshoot from Android Studio]

You can also build your project from command line and get the right path.

Inside *values.xml* file in line 172(in your case different line) you would find a `<declare-styleable>` with property named *"color"*(*"showText"* in your case). Most probably it is your own styleable that you have to change to get rid of the duplicate.

So now, when you know the reason, you can locate that property in your project module and replace it with different name. I guess it will be located inside */values/attrs.xml* file.

Comment: The weird thing here is that `<declare-styleable>` defines a scope for attributes, so it should not collide, in my case it was `CursorAdapter_layout` (mine) VS `SearchView_layout` (support). Do you think there's a deeper bug here, or just the support lib introducing new attrs will break other apps now and in future?

Comment: I think its the latter. It will force us to specify unique names for our attributes, maybe it's ok. On the other hand it looks like a side affect of the merger that Google did not predict. I guess we would have to ask them.

Comment: @DamianPetla, you are just awesome.....thanks a lot....saved a lot of time for me.

Answer (score 5):

I spent last two hours on the same issue and in my case the problem was that I had defined my own attribute "showText" (in res/values/attrs.xml) which was in collision with attribute defined in  `<declare-styleable name="SwitchCompat">`.

This problem does not exist when using appcompat-v7:20 but with appcompat-v7:21 build fails.

Comment: Still fails appcompat-v7:22.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the whole play services like this following example 1

example 1: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'

Use those services that you want to use in you application. For example if you want to use Google+ service than use as following example 2

example 2: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.5.0'

for more services visit: [Setting Up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)